# How best to use SVN in this situation?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

Looking for advice on how I should be using SVN within my product development.

At the moment I'm on version 2.2 of my product and have begun to use SVN with eclipse in order to keep track of my code. However I'm due to begin work on version 3 of the product which is essentially identical to 2.2 with a few big overhauls and some new features.

The problem is though 2.2 will still be under going bug fixing and a few minor features/tweaks with maybe 2-3 more releases before it becomes stationery and no more work is done on it - hopefully in time for version 3 release. So at the moment if my trunk is 2.2 with a stable tag at this point, where do I go from here? Keep in mind that i'd expect 3 to be branch from this tag in the trunk, but as 2.2 and 3 have similar classes if i make a minor change or bug fix i want it to relfect in version 3 rather than have to implement the bug fix twice, both in v2.2(trunk) and v3 branch.

Its also worth noting that my v3 branch may have branches on it for 'experimental' features that may not enter the first stable release of that particular product.

Any ideas on best practice for this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I realise you just started to use Subversion, but you may wish to consider Git instead. This article may help: [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach would be to have a separate svn branch for each functional branch of development.

One instantiation of this would be to create a 2.x branch that will be where you do all of your development on the 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, ... series.  This would be based off of wherever you are currently and you could use tags to denote each of the release points.  You can also spawn off new branches for critical release fixes in the future, should they arise (e.g., 2.3.x).  Then you could continue your primary development on trunk.

You'd of course use `svn merge` (as described at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.html) to handle the merging between branches, should it be necessary.  I strongly recommend using the latest version of Subversion (say, 1.5) as older versions required that you manually track the changes that had already been merged, whereas newer versions handle tracking that information for you.

To handle simple bug fixes that you want to merge down or up between branches, you could use [cherry-picking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) to move just those changes between branches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My main issue is with the ability to make changes in 2.x that i want/ expect to show up in v3. As version 3 is essentially version 2 with extnded features. Say for instance i have started work on v3 and i decide to implement a pretty big change regarding searching for instance in v2.3. Any changes additions in 2.3 i'd expect to have in v3 as well. If i merge however I dont want any of the features of v3 to enter into v2.x

Comment: You can periodically merge from whatever branch(es) you are using to develop 2.x into whatever branches you are using to develop 3.x.  You control the direction of merge, and how to resolve any conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this repository

```
    ROOT
    |-- trunk
    |-- tags
    |   `-- 2.2 => copy of branches/version_2
    `-- branches
        |-- version_2 => copy of trunk at 2.2
        |-- version_3_experimental => copy of trunk at 2.2
        `-- version_3 => copy of trunk at 2.2
```

You make every development for your version 3 in trunk, and any bug fix is done in the version_2 branch. If anything developed for version 2 should be in the version 3, you merge it in trunk. Afterward, you merge your trunk in branches/version_3. That way, your trunk keep growing according to the version 3.

When you have completed your version 2, create a tags from the version_2 branche.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [svn merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html) to merge branches of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your development will look something like this:

```
                                              branch
                                              2.x -------------->
                                               |             |bring some more
                                               |  trunk 3.0  |changes if necessary
   trunk   --------------------------------------------------------------->
    2.2 stable        |      |      |        |  *     incorporated
       |              |      |      |        |  |Merge
   create branch     periodically bring      |  |branch 3 back
       |              | changes from trunk   |  |to trunk
       *              *      *      *        *  |
       branch------------------------------------X branch ends
         3                                            here
```

My suggestion is to delay creation of 2.x branch just before you merge 3.x to trunk. 
So that number of merges can be decreased.

Any changes from there on can be brought to trunk(3.x) but not the other way. This is typical approach when you phase out 2.x in favor of 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My main issue is with the ability to make changes in 2.x that i want/ expect to show up in v3. As version 3 is essentially version 2 with extnded features. I dont want to ship/upgrade to customers that are used to having certain features that arent available nor do i wish to implement twice. Say i have started work on v3 and i decide to implement a big change regarding searching 4 instance in v2.3. Any changes/additions in 2.3 i'd expect to have in v3 as well. If i merge however I dont want any of the features of v3 to enter into v2.x they need to be seperate.

Comment: @Franco : I agree with you. In fact, while I was writing my answer I saw that yvoyer has already talked about it. So I left answering that portion. I would have preferred to create a branch for 2.x and 3.x from the stable trunk line. Keep the 2.x copy. Get fixes in trunk back to 2.x line but at some point to bring 3.x to trunk since at some point we have to make that as base for further development.